# Rounding issues with complex numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rounding, complex-numbers, ruby-2.2

In IRB (using Ruby version 2.2), if I try getting the square root of -1 by raising it to the power of 0.5, I get strange results:

```
(-1)**(0.5)
  => (6.123233995736766e-17+1.0i)
```

This looks like a really close approximation, but does anybody know where the rounding issue is coming from?

Comment: From floating point?